# Umbraco v5 RTM causes iis express to crash - suspected security/config setting

Tags: umbraco

So I'm convinced that the problem is permissions related, but I can't put my finger on it.  When running v5 RTM via iis express / webmatrix the site spins up just fine, but then crashes within 7-8 secs with the error message "unhandled excpetion in iisexpress.exe".  I've tried setting trust to medium in web.config, which causes a YSOD with excpetion

```
"System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."
```

I'm working on a machine connected to a Windows domain and have temporarily given "Everyone" full control over the folder containing the v5 site.

Am I missing a specific setting for a service account attached to IIS Express (I thought IIS Express ran as a user process and I am a local admin on the machine)?  I'm on an XP machine and don't have the option of installing full blown IIS 7.  I currently run other MVC3 projects from within VS 2010 without issue.  Also, Umbraco 4.7.x runs within my iisexpress without issue.  At this point I'm just grasping for straws in the hopes of problem remediation.  I REALLY want to leverage v5 as part of a metadata management project I'm starting, but obviously will be stuck with v4 if configuration will be an issue for myself or members of my team.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Here's the log file contents:

```
2012-02-08 14:19:52,441 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Start Initialise
2012-02-08 14:19:52,472 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Creating shadow copy folder and querying for dlls
2012-02-08 14:19:52,488 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Shadow copying assemblies
2012-02-08 14:19:52,488 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Core\lib\Umbraco.Cms.Web.Editors.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,503 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Umbraco.Cms.Web.Editors, Version=5.0.310.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,503 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Core\lib\Umbraco.CMS.Web.ParameterEditors.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,503 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Umbraco.CMS.Web.ParameterEditors, Version=5.0.310.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,503 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Core\lib\Umbraco.Cms.Web.PropertyEditors.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,519 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Umbraco.Cms.Web.PropertyEditors, Version=5.0.310.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,519 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Core\lib\Umbraco.Cms.Web.Tasks.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,519 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Umbraco.Cms.Web.Tasks, Version=5.0.310.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,519 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Core\lib\Umbraco.Cms.Web.Trees.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,535 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Umbraco.Cms.Web.Trees, Version=5.0.310.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,535 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Packages\Examine\lib\Examine.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,550 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Examine, Version=2.10.0.292, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,550 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Packages\Examine\lib\Lucene.Net.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,566 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,566 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Packages\Examine\lib\Umbraco.Framework.Persistence.Examine.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,582 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Umbraco.Framework.Persistence.Examine, Version=5.0.310.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,582 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - C:\umbraco5\App_Plugins\Packages\SystemInfo\lib\Umbraco.Cms.Packages.SystemInfo.dll to c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f21960d6\a904bc5
2012-02-08 14:19:52,582 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - Adding to BuildManager: 'Umbraco.Cms.Packages.SystemInfo, Version=5.0.310.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
2012-02-08 14:19:52,597 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.System.PluginManager [(null)] - End Initialise (took 130ms)
2012-02-08 14:19:52,628 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.UI.MvcApplication [(null)] - Http application warmup
2012-02-08 14:19:52,769 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Framework.DependencyManagement.AbstractContainerBuilder [(null)] - Start AddDependencyDemandBuilder FrameworkSetup
2012-02-08 14:19:52,800 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Framework.DependencyManagement.AbstractContainerBuilder [(null)] - End AddDependencyDemandBuilder (took 32ms)
2012-02-08 14:19:52,800 [5] INFO  Umbraco.Cms.Web.UmbracoWebApplication [(null)] - Start called. Product info: Umbraco 5.0.0 RTM build 5.0.310.16
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm that's very strange (the first part), do you ever get any pages returned at all within those 7-8 seconds or does it look like it's crashing basically on app startup?

We don't support medium trust yet so the second part / error message you're getting is normal in that sense. But the first one is odd. There's a file at /App_Data/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog.txt that it tries to write to, could you check a) it's writing to there properly and isn't the source of the crash and b) if you have anything in there worth posting?

Comment: Here's the contents of the file - it's all that written from the point of spin-up - the crash appears to happen before anything is response is sent to the browser. File contents appear in question per comment length limit